# CCSpriteFrame rectInPixels on retina device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, retina

I am creating an explosion sprite animation with the following code, the image is 440x440 pixels (a 4x4 grid of 110x110 pixel frames), with a -hd image of 880x880 (which is being loaded on the retina device);

```
CCTexture *explosionTexture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:@"explosion.png"];
NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray array];
int frameCount = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:explosionTexture
                                                  rectInPixels:CGRectMake(x*110, y*110, 110, 110)
                                                       rotated:NO
                                                        offset:CGPointZero
                                                  originalSize:CGSizeMake(440, 440)];
        [frames addObject:frame];
        frameCount++;
        if (frameCount == 14) break;
    }
}
```

This works fine on non retina iPhone but when i test on retina iPhone the rect is wrong (each frame is 1/4 the size it should be)

I have put the frame.rect and the x / y from the for loops in an `NSLog` and it shows this on the retina device;

```
2014-05-09 23:22:10.872 SimpleGame[4131:70b] x:0, y:0
2014-05-09 23:22:10.872 SimpleGame[4131:70b] frame.rect:{{0, 0}, {55, 55}}
2014-05-09 23:22:10.873 SimpleGame[4131:70b] x:1, y:0
2014-05-09 23:22:10.873 SimpleGame[4131:70b] frame.rect:{{55, 0}, {55, 55}}
2014-05-09 23:22:10.874 SimpleGame[4131:70b] x:2, y:0
2014-05-09 23:22:10.874 SimpleGame[4131:70b] frame.rect:{{110, 0}, {55, 55}}
```

and this on the non retina device;

```
2014-05-09 23:22:10.872 SimpleGame[4131:70b] x:0, y:0
2014-05-09 23:22:10.872 SimpleGame[4131:70b] frame.rect:{{0, 0}, {110, 110}}
2014-05-09 23:22:10.873 SimpleGame[4131:70b] x:1, y:0
2014-05-09 23:22:10.873 SimpleGame[4131:70b] frame.rect:{{110, 0}, {110, 110}}
2014-05-09 23:22:10.874 SimpleGame[4131:70b] x:2, y:0
2014-05-09 23:22:10.874 SimpleGame[4131:70b] frame.rect:{{220, 0}, {110, 110}}
```

The docs do say (and is obvious by the name) `rectInPixels` is calculated in pixels (not points). Is this correct? if so this seems completely counter intuitive and unhelpful to me, why not simply calculate in points? so how do i calculate the correct rect for retina and non-retina?

This is really confusing me as i'm positive this was working as is a day ago and all I have changed since it was working is the dimensions of the image.

It's late so I may just be missing something really obvious but I can not seem to figure this out so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame rect you log is in points again, so this is actually correct based on your code. What you are missing is to multiply the pixel size with [contentScale](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/Classes/CCTexture.html#//api/name/contentScale) to create actual pixel coordinates and size for Retina textures:

```
CGFloat texScale = explosionTexture.contentScale;
CGRect rectInPixels = CGRectMake(x*110*texScale, y*110*texScale, 110*texScale, 110*texScale);
```

This is assuming that you have a 2x scaled texture with -hd suffix (explosion-hd.png). If you only have one image the code above won't change anything because you would be using the same texture on a display that has 4x as many pixels, therefore the texture would appear to be half as big as on non-retina devices.

Comment: I didnt know about the contentScale property. I ended up getting around it by getting the actual pixel value of the image and using that;
`int explosionWidth = explosionTexture.pixelWidth;`
`CGRect rectInPixels = CGRectMake(x*(explosionWidth/4), y*(explosionHeight/4), explosionWidth/4, explosionHeight/4);`

Comment: But using the contentScale property is definitely a better way to go about it. Thanks for the help